# IIS 7 courtesy trailing slash appears to clash with my URL Rewrite rule

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm just starting to work with URL Rewrite 2.0 in c#.net web.config.  My web.config looks like this:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
  </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This should remove the trailing slash on a URL.  When I run the app, the rule appears to work at the root level, so this...

```xml
www.mysite.com/
```

...gets redirected to...

```xml
www.mysite.com/
```

...but the redirect doesn't work at other levels.

So the problem is that this...

```xml
www.mysite.com/pages/
```

...ends up with the trailing slash staying in place and if I try this...

```xml
www.mysite.com/pages
```

...the trailing slash is actually APPENDED.

My guess is that this is the 'courtesy trailing slash' that IIS 7 adds, but I don't know how to get the URL Rewrite rule to override it?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a year old, but I was having the same issue so I decided to post the solution.

The problem is:

```
<match url="(.*)/$" />
```

should be

```
<match url="(.*)\/$" />
```

Once that is changed everything works.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference.